# Fragments and android life cycle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've got something strange with my android app.

If I run main activity and then go through few fragments, I'll see main activity after hiding/unhiding the app. If I press "back", it will show the fragment that was shown right before hiding. But sometimes app shows me the last fragment after unhiding. How can I make my app show the last fragment everytime if it's possible? Or how can I make my app save its state?

Comment: I think you have to save the numer of the current fragment in onSaveInstance() and use this number to reload the fragment in the onCreate method. Check here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html . Though not very clear about your question (..hiding/unhiding app part), i think it may be a back stack  management issue.

Comment: @Maxouille, but I want to run exactly the same intsance of fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want when the "back" button is pressed, the **last fragment** should be displayed. For this you can depend on the `addToBackStack` method to handle the Back press.
From Google code snippet @ [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Note: In this case newFragment is your last fragment.